# How to read the number of documents only once?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read the number of documents in a subcollection for that I am using the below code, but this is reading the number of documents as many times the documents in the subcollection, I want to ensure to read once only not as many times the documents, please assist, thank you

```
   func getNumberOfComments() {
        Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").document(postId).collection("comments").getDocuments{ (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error{
                print (error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                if let snapshot = snapshot{
                    for document in snapshot.documents{
                        let data = document.data()

                        self.length = snapshot.count
                        print("counting " , self.length!)
                       // var length2 = data.count
                       // print ("printing ", length2)

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this is reading the number of documents as many times the documents in the subcollection

This is happening because the following lines of code:

```
self.length = snapshot.count
print("counting " , self.length!)
```

Are called at every iteration. If you want to be printed only once, then simply get the above lines of code out of the loop by moving them right before the for loop starts:

```
func getNumberOfComments() {
    Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").document(postId).collection("comments").getDocuments{ (snapshot, error) in
        if let error = error{
            print (error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            if let snapshot = snapshot{
                self.length = snapshot.count
                print("counting " , self.length!)

                for document in snapshot.documents{
                    let data = document.data()
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```